# How to have a raspberry Pi automatically open up a program on boot?

Tags: raspbian, pi-2, boot, scratch

I was wondering if their was a way for a Raspberry Pi to automatically open up a file on boot. (A scratch project)

Comment: This has been asked and answered many times.  What search terms did you use to find existing answers?